# Sorting get_adjacent_post by meta key value - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I've hit a bit of a bump in the road with a solution I came up with.

I'm using the get_adjacent_posts function to return the previous post within a loop

```
    <div class="timeline">
    <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'case', 'cases' => $term->slug, 'order' => 'DEC', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'wpcf-date'); $query = new WP_Query($args); while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php
            $previous_post = get_adjacent_post(true, '', true, 'cases'); //Get The previous post
            $prev_year = date("Y", get_post_meta($previous_post->ID, 'wpcf-date', true)); //Get the year of the previous post
            $entry_year = date("Y", (types_render_field("date", array("raw"=>"true")))); //Get the year of the current post

            if ($prev_year != $entry_year) { 
        ?>

        <strong class="entry-year"><?php echo $entry_year; ?></strong>

        <?php } ?>

        <div class="timeline-entry">
            <span class="entry-date"><?php echo types_render_field("date", array("raw"=>"false")); ?></span>
            <span class="entry-citation"><?php echo types_render_field("citation-court", array("raw"=>"false")); ?></span>
            <strong class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to show a 'timeline' of posts and echo out the year (custom field) only once per block of posts that have the same year. My solution is working aside from the fact that the get_adjacent_post function doesn't honour the sorting that has been applied in my original query. I need to sort the get_adjacent_post function by the meta key 'wpcf-date'.

I believe get_adjacent_posts can be filtered to output what I want but I have no idea how to do it. If anyone can help me out that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
previous_posts_link('previous',$query->max_num_pages)
```

edited:-

```
function get_previous_post_id($wp_query) {
   if ($wp_query->current_post == $wp_query->post_count) return 0;
$previous_post = $wp_query->posts[$wp_query->current_post - 1];
return $previous_post ->ID;
}
```

use this in your functions.php and

```
$previous_post_id=get_previous_post_id($query);
```

on where you need previous post id. $query is the string you generated from your Wp_query

p.s. last post shall return 0;

Comment: I don't want a link to the previous post I just need to get the ID of the previous post.

Comment: it has been edited again .. might be this will wok out for your Wp_query you have already run.